# How does work the next block election in blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, mining-theory

In the mining process each miner will create a block with the transactions found in the pool and will start the calculation of nonce, the miner with greater hash power will finish the job first and announce the block.

When the process starts the miners will start the calculation again(the slowest and the fastest), imagine that we have 2 pools of mining and the slower needs 2 hour to calculate a nonce and the faster 2 minutes, the window of 10 minutes will have a winner and the slower have to start the caculation again.

How does lottery work to the solve this problem?

Comment: In this question no have the answer for my question. Because they comment about a lottery, by nobody explained how the algorithm solve.

Comment: Mining is a lottery, as the answers in that post explains. Your understanding of the process is incorrect.

Comment: @G.Maxwell I edit the question and created a scenario. Can you answer? What's the correct view?

Comment: The flaw in your question is that "time to calculate a nonce" is *random, not deterministic*.  It may be that A needs 2 minutes and B needs 2 hours *on average*, but that does not imply that A will *always* beat B; B can still get lucky.